# Determine if ldap attribute must be unique value across the entire Domain

Tags: active-directory, ldap, domaincontroller

There are attributes that must be unique (sAMAccountName, legacyExchangeDN, distinguishedname,objectguid) in an active directory Domain.

My question is, how do i know if attribute must be unique in the active directory ?

I assume this is defined somewhere in the schema of the ldap, because on the attribute itself, you cannot determine it, but when trying to add 2 mailboxes with the same name, you get duplication error - so its probably on the server somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell from the schema. Here is an article from Microsoft on the topic: [Understanding unique attributes in Active Directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/10/understanding-unique-attributes-in-active-directory/)

It says:

> Active Directory does not provide any means for identifying unique
>   attributes. Some attributes are unique as a result of their specific
>   processing rules defined by the protocols. In a broader AD view, this
>   translates into associated constraints and triggers applied to objects
>   during replica update operations. These rules depend on objects and
>   may apply to a naming context (NC), a container, a distinguished name
>   (DN), a domain, or an entire forest, etc.

So, basically, it has it's own rules for enforcing uniqueness on certain fields. You cannot add or remove from the fields it enforces uniqueness on.

Comment: Is there a way to retreive a list of the unique attributes of current rules/proccessors?

Comment: There is no programmatic way to get a list, but you also don't need to. It's a short list that cannot change. There is a list in that article I linked to.